# Solr search much slower for logged in users

Tags: performance, search

I've set up Solr on a Drupal installation with around 11000 indexed nodes. I'm using [Apache Solr Search Integration](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr) module and the FacetAPI interface.

However, I'm finding that searches take around 2 seconds to return results when accessing search anonymously but 9 seconds when logged in! There's no obvious reason for this discrepancy -- for example, none of the content nodes have permissions applied.

I've run Profiler against both approaches and there is a big discrepancy in the number of queries issued: 216 queries and 1644ms vs 496 queries and 8545ms.

There's no similar discrepancy in time for other pages, eg loading a taxonomy page, which makes me rule out authenticated content generated within other blocks.

I'm a little lost where to start. Why would a search when authenticated be so much more complex, and what can be done to improve performance?

**Edit:** On deeper inspection of the queries, the cause of performance issues does appear to be related to the fact that results can't be cached for authenticated users. The 2 most expensive queries when authenticated are a drupal_lookup_path call (115ms) and menu_get_item (71ms), which compares to 0.5ms and 0.2ms executing anonymously.

Any thoughts on how to either:

(1) reduce the performance impact of operating in an authenticated context, or

(2) always execute search in anonymous context, even when logged in (there's no difference in the results which would be returned)?

Comment: "There's no obvious reason for this" - there may be, by default cache does not apply for logged-in users, so maybe it affects solr communication, too?

Comment: Do you know if the extra time is in actual solr requests or other drupal related processing? When you give query counts are you talking Drupal database queries or solr queries?

Comment: Have you installed the Devel module and had a look at the query log when you're logged in? Show us any problematic queries you find. Also, do you notice in massive performance issues on pages / routes other than your search results? As Molot said authenticated users will in general see worse performance as their access rights etc need to be checked on every bootstrap.

Comment: There are Drupal queries. I'm pretty sure it's not Solr. If I execute the query directly from the Solr admin panel the results are lightning fast.